# Are there any encryption schemes that enable to permute homomorphically?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

According to the [Barrington's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29#Barrington.27s_theorem), any circuit in NC1 can be converted to a branching program, whose main operation is the composition of permutations (along with the choosing of permutations according to inputs, which we omit here) . So I wonder whether there is a scheme that can directly encrypt the [two-line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Notation) of permutation, which also enables to do the composition of permutations on the ciphertext, except the general methods by using FHE/Multilinear mapping on permutation matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do *bounded-length* "composition of permutations on the ciphertext"

by [Evaluating Branching Programs on Encrypted Data](http://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2007/43920574/43920574.pdf).

Public key length and ciphertext length both scale linearly with the number of permutations.

*Leveled* FHE can evaluate arbitrary-length compositions of permutations, since iterated composition of permutations can be carried out in low depth. $\:$ (So, one does not need full FHE.)

I don't know of any less general methods than that for arbitrary-length compositions.

Comment: By a quick check, I think that this paper in fact described an interactive protocol based on OT. Do you have any hints about a non-interactive cryptographic scheme? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: _I_ don't have any hints about that, but _their_ hint about that forms section 3.1, which starts on page 7. $\hspace{.4 in}$